# IndexError: list index out of range even though it works on a single file

Tags: python, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to extract some values from a group of CSV files in a certain folder.

I actually made it work on a single folder, but now after changing the code
to read all the CSV files inside the folder, it shows this error:

```
File "potato.py", line 20, in <module>
    jerkiness.append(row[8].replace(';', ' '))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```py
dirfile = "C:\VQA_excel"
grenata = os.listdir(dirfile)
for file in grenata:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        jerkiness = []
        jerkinessfloat = []
        #cle = open("C:\VQA_excel\" + file)
        cle = os.path.join(dirfile, file)
        print cle
        with open(cle, 'r') as tc:
            excel = csv.reader(tc)
            for row in excel:
                jerkiness.append(row[8].replace(';', ' '))
```

The expected result is a list with the values from the CSV files.

Comment: It seems one of the files doesn't have enough fields and `row` does not have nine elements.
Try to add `print( len(row) )` before `for row in excel:`

Comment: print len(excel)
**TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()**